# Toggle button visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a personal website that it's kinda of working but I want to improve my code and how it is done, so I want to do a Toggle Button but:

```js
function toggle_visibility() {
  var l = document.getElementById('links');
  var p = document.getElementById('projects');

  if (l.style.display == 'inline' || p.style.display = '') {
    l.style.display = 'none';
    p.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    l.style.display = 'inline';
    p.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#links    { display: inline; }
#projects { display: none;   }
```

All code for the website can be found here: 
https://github.com/moonfz/moonfz.github.io

It is still a project that I'm working on, **CSS** should be optimized soon.
I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: This question really belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just a tip - use more meaningful variable names because on bigger projects, `l` and `p` have zero meaning :)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: You should try to avoid changing CSS trough JS. Always try to apply classes instead of using `.css()`. 

And, you should also listen to @Timmy.

Comment: You have missed one more `=`, in here `p.style.display = ''`

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will helps you.

```js
function toggle_visibility() {
debugger;
  var l = document.getElementById('links');
    var d = document.getElementById('project');
    if (d.className == 'DispayButton') {
 debugger
  d.className = "";
   l.className += "DispayButton";    
  } 
   else  {
 debugger
  l.className = "";
   d.className += "DispayButton";    
  }    
  }
```

```css
.DispayButton {Display:none;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
<input type=button id="links" text="Switch Mode" onclick="toggle_visibility()" class="" value="links">
<input type=button id="project" text="Switch Mode" onclick="toggle_visibility()" class="DispayButton" value="project">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only add or remove classes with this method not amend classes. Just seems cleaner for future users where all code and its purpose would be clearly separated. If not you might get someone using absolutes in css (YUK!)

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes instead of setting the display itself on the elements. You can then use "classList" to toggle them on click. Here is a quick writeup about how you can use classList for that: https://js-tricks.io/blog/how-to-toggle-a-class-in-pure-javascript